# Using Regular Expressions (RegExp) on a array in a switch statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, switch-statement

In the spot labeled WHAT GOES HERE?, I am trying to use RegExp to alter the letters in the string while leaving other characters unaltered.

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
  str = str.split("");
  counter = 0;
  str.forEach(function(i) {
    switch (i) {
      case <!--WHAT GOES HERE?--!>:
        newCharCode = i.charCodeAt(0) + 1;
        i = String.fromCharCode(newCharCode);
        str[counter] = i;
        counter += 1;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
  str = str.join("");
  return str;
}
console.log(LetterChanges('gregz1'));
```

I would think the RegExp /[a-zA-Z]/g should work, but it doesn't.  Any suggestions?

See the Pen [Using Regular Expressions (RegExp) on a array in a switch statement in Javascript](https://codepen.io/jonnawhat/pen/eVeEpr/) by Jon ([@jonnawhat](https://codepen.io/jonnawhat)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: switch-case comparsions are equivalent to `===`, use `if` conditions

Comment: [A string is iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which means you can use `for...of` to loop through the individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `switch` as in the snippet below. But it's considered a bad practice (Thanks @Bergi for their comment). So you'd better use plain `if` statement.

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {
  str = str.split("");
  counter = 0;
  str.forEach(function(i) {
    switch (true) {
      case /[a-z]/.test(i):
        newCharCode = i.charCodeAt(0) + 1;
        i = String.fromCharCode(newCharCode);
        str[counter] = i;
        counter += 1;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
  str = str.join("");
  return str;
}
console.log(LetterChanges('gregz1'));
```

Comment: I looked. I didn't like what I saw.

Comment: @Bergi, why not?

Comment: Because `switch(true)` is an obfuscating antipattern. Plain `if` statements should be used instead.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for your comment. But PO asked how to use `switch` in their particular case. They did not ask for code review. So I do not think it was bad if they knew this usecase. Anyway I've updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: @KoshVery you are correct.  There was something fundamental about switch cases I was trying to figure out and this has been very helpful.  Thank you!